# How to group documents which object array has a value less than a given value but the max one

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this kind of document:

```
{
    "_id" : "16",
    "name" : "SB15",
    "category_id" : 3,
    "level" : 2,
    "sizes" : [ 
        {
            "v" : 34.78
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 32.15
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 35.86
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 39.4
        }, 
        {
            "v" : 24.01
        }
    ]
}
```

I need that for each "category_id" value find documents whose "size.v" has the higher value less than a given number and the level is equal to a given number and limit documents to 4 for each category_id

the result should be something like this if I look for a "size.v" less than 35

```
{
    "_id" : 3, /* the category_id */
    "models" : [
        {
            "name": "SB15",
            "level": 2,
            "size":  {
                "v" : 34.78, /* the higher value in sizes array less than 35 */ 
                "h" : 6.4,
                "w" : 0.20,
                "t" : 0.03
            } 
        }
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the general idea would be to find the difference from the target value and then sort the results:

For MongoDB 2.6 onwards, it's probably best to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) on the array before [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), as there is less processing overhead:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Calculate the difference
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "sizes": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$sizes",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "v": "$$el.v",
                    "diff": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$gt": [ 35, "$$el.v" },
                            999999,
                            { "$subtract": [ 35, "$$el.v" ] }
                        ]
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }},

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$sizes" },

    // Sort to smallest difference 
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "sizes.diff": 1 } },

    // Get the $first after sort
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "category_id": { "$first": "$category_id" },
        "level": { "$first": "$level" },
        "size_v": { "$first": "$sizes.v" }
    }},

    // Since you cannot have nested paths in a $group
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "size": {
            "v": "$size_v"
        }
    }},

    // Group up by category
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$category_id",
        "models": { 
            "$push": {
                "name": "$name",
                "level": "$level",
                "size": "$size"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

In earlier versions `$unwind` first:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$sizes" },
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "sizes": {
            "v": "$sizes.v",
            "diff": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$gt": [ 35, "$sizes.v" ] },
                    99999,
                    { "$subtract": [ 35, "$sizes.v" ] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "sizes.diff": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "category_id": { "$first": "$category_id" },
        "level": { "$first": "$level" },
        "size_v": { "$first": "$sizes.v" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "category_id": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "size": {
            "v": "$size_v"
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$category_id",
        "models": { 
            "$push": {
                "name": "$name",
                "level": "$level",
                "size": "$size"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

The main calculatation is done within the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), where first you look to see if the value is greater than the target, and if so then assign a "diff" that is a large value. Further away from possible intervals the better.

Where it is actually less than the target, [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) the value from the target. The smaller the number in result, the closer it is.

But the basic case is to calculate the difference and then [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) so the smallest value is on top. Then you can pick that value using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) as you [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again.

Also note that `$group` cannot have nested objects as keys, so totals are first made as `"size_v"` and then renamed to `"size.v"` in a later `$project` stage to accomodate the transform.

Comment: good call, nice approach. I will try to play around. thank you @Blakes Seven

Comment: Just a question: where is better to filter for "level" $eq to a target value in the pipeline?

Comment: I put a $match as the first stage of the pipeline. is that correct?

Comment: @davelab No idea what you are asking. I'm just answering the question you asked here. If you have new questions, then it's best to post them in whole form so people can clearly understand them. This answers the question as you asked it.

Comment: actually in the question i asked also for: " level is equal to a given number and limit documents to 4 for each category_id".